# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier; I don't understand why

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

When ever I am putting the ajax part in comments it works just fine. I get the json data in my console, but the moment I put the ajax part back on, the entire function doesn't work and the button that triggers the function is laid to waste.
The error that I get is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
function edit_user(email)
{
        element = '<div align="center">';
    element +='<p id="video_upload_heading" style="font-
    size:24px">Change Profile<br><br>Email: <b><i>'+email+'</i>
    </b> </p>';
    element +='<form id="formdata_upload">';
    element += '<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" 
    name="fname" id="fname" class="container" 
    style="color:black; width:300px; height:30px; 
    padding:7px">';
    element += '<br><br><input type="text" placeholder="Last 
    Name" name="lname" id="lname" class="container" 
    style="color:black; width:300px; height:30px;padding:7px">';
    element += '<br><br><input type="date" data-date-inline-
    picker="true" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="dob" 
    id="dob" class="container" style="color:black; width:300px; 
    height:30px; padding:7px">';
    element += '<br><br><input type="text" placeholder="New 
    Password" name="pswd" id="pswd" class="container" 
    style="color:black; width:300px; height:30px; 
    padding:7px">';
    element += '<br><br><input type="hidden" value='+email+' 
    name="email" id="email" class="container" 
    style="color:black; width:300px; height:30px; 
    padding:7px">';
    element += '<br><br><input type="button" id="upload_button" 
    style="color:white; background:orange; width:90px; 
    height:30px;font-size:16px" value="Upload">';
    element += '<br><br></form>'
    element += '<div align="center" id="upload-respose"></div>'
    element += '</div>'

    // Problem code line
    element += '<script>';
    element += '$("#upload_button").on("click",function(){'
        element += 'console.log({email:$("#email").val(), 
    fname:$("#fname").val(), lname:$("#lname").val(), 
    dob:$("#dob").val(),  pswd:$("#pswd").val()})';
        element += '$.post("user_detail_update", 
    {email:$("#email").val(), fname:$("#fname").val(), 
    lname:$("#lname").val(), dob:$("#dob").val(), 
    pswd:$("#pswd").val()}), function(data){'
    element += ' console.log(data);'
        element += '});'
        element += '});</script>'


    $("#response").html(element);
 }
```

Comment: Looks like a closing bracket (`)`) out of place after `pswd:$("#pswd").val()}`

Comment: When you find yourself building up code in strings like that, stop, sit back, and look for a different solution. It's basically never necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have this HTML and script instead of creating a string

There is no longer a need to delegate the click on the upload button and I removed the form tags which are not used

```js
$(function() {
  $("#upload_button").on("click", function(e) {
    $.post("user_detail_update", {
        email: $("#email").val(),
        fname: $("#fname").val(),
        lname: $("#lname").val(),
        dob: $("#dob").val(),
        pswd: $("#pswd").val()
      },
      function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
  });

  function edit_user(email) {
    $("#emailVal").text(email);
    $("#email").val(email);
    $("#formdata_upload").show();
  }

  $("#showUpload").on("click", function() {
    edit_user($(this).data("email"));
  });
});
```

```css
#formdata_upload {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showUpload" data-email="x@y.com">Test</button>
<div align="center" id="formdata_upload">
  <p id="video_upload_heading" style="font-size:24px">Change Profile Email: <b><i id="emailVal"></i></b></p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" id="fname" class="container" style="color:black; width:300px; height:30px; padding:7px">
  <br><br><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" id="lname" class="container" style="color:black; width:300px; height:30px;padding:7px">
  <br><br><input type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="dob" id="dob" class="container" style="color:black; width:300px; height:30px; padding:7px">
  <br><br><input type="text" placeholder="New Password" name="pswd" id="pswd" class="container" style="color:black; width:300px; height:30px; padding:7px">
  <br><br><input type="hidden" value='' name="email" id="email" class="container" style="color:black; width:300px; height:30px; padding:7px">
  <br><br><input type="button" id="upload_button" style="color:white; background:orange; width:90px; height:30px;font-size:16px" value="Upload">
  <br><br>
  <div align="center" id="upload-respose"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of problems:

1. You have a line break in the middle of a string literal:

   ```
   element += '<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" 
   name="fname" id="fname" class="container"
   ```

   JavaScript doesn't allow unescaped line breaks.
2. This:

   ```
   element += '});</script>'
   ```

   That `</script>` ends your script, even though it's in `'`.

   Instead, either:

   1. Move your JavaScript into an external file, so `</script>` isn't special, or
   2. Break that up somehow; this is common (note the backslash):

      ```
      element += '});<\/script>'
      ```

Comment: That is a mistake. Thank you for pointing it out. I put the string in double quotes. But this still doesn't solve my main error

Comment: @GourabChattopadhyay: *"I put the string in double quotes."* You still can't have unescaped line breaks. Doesn't matter which kind of quote you use. Fundamentally, the browser will point at or very near the syntax error. There's nothing for it but to work it through yourself.